# ESX performance stats in Logstash

Tags: vmware-esx, syslog, logstash, elk

Dose anyone know if it is possible to collect ESX Performance Stats in LogStash/ELK stack? looking to see if I can collect ESXTOP data for use in the ELK stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example input, you would just need rsyslog or a logging tool to send logs to the input port (1514 in this example) and then filter the data:

**Input**

```
input {
        tcp {
                type => "VMware"
                port => "1514"
        }
}
```

**Filter**

```
filter {
    if "VMware" in [tags] {
            multiline {
                    pattern => "-->"
                    what => "previous"
            }
            grok {
                    break_on_match => true
                    match => [
                            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{SYSLOGPROG:syslog_program}: (?<message-body>(?<message_system_info>(?:\[%{DATA:message_thread_id} %{DATA:syslog_level} \'%{DATA:message_service}\'\ ?%{DATA:message_opID}])) \[%{DATA:message_service_info}]\ (?<syslog_message>(%{GREEDYDATA})))",
                            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{SYSLOGPROG:syslog_program}: (?<message-body>(?<message_system_info>(?:\[%{DATA:message_thread_id} %{DATA:syslog_level} \'%{DATA:message_service}\'\ ?%{DATA:message_opID}])) (?<syslog_message>(%{GREEDYDATA})))",
                            "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{SYSLOGPROG:syslog_program}: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"
                    ]
            }
            syslog_pri { }
            date {
                    match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-ddHH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
                    timezone => "UTC"
            }
            mutate {
                    replace => [ "@source_host", "%{syslog_hostname}" ]
            }
            mutate {
                    replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
            }
            if "Device naa" in [message] {
                    grok {
                            break_on_match => false
                            match => [
                                    "message", "Device naa.%{WORD:device_naa} performance has %{WORD:device_status}%{GREEDYDATA} of %{INT:datastore_latency_from}%{GREEDYDATA} to %{INT:datastore_latency_to}",
                                    "message", "Device naa.%{WORD:device_naa} performance has %{WORD:device_status}%{GREEDYDATA} from %{INT:datastore_latency_from}%{GREEDYDATA} to %{INT:datastore_latency_to}"
                            ]
                    }
            }
            if "connectivity issues" in [message] {
                    grok {
                            match => [
                                    "message", "Hostd: %{GREEDYDATA} : %{DATA:device_access} to volume %{DATA:device_id} %{DATA:datastore} (following|due to)"
                            ]
                    }
            }
            if "WARNING" in [message] {
                    grok {
                            match => [
                                    "message", "WARNING: %{GREEDYDATA:vmware_warning_msg}"
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: if the ESX host is already syslogging to a syslog server and from there Logstash is picking it up, will this work in that context?

Comment: Yes, you can use any type of logger just as long as you set the port that logstash will expect the data on and set udp/tcp if it's an option.  Try this to verify log data on your receiving machine:  `telnet <hostname> <port>`

Comment: perfect, I will try this out and mark answered once I get it working.

Comment: Hope it works, you may have to play with the filter if there are parts that aren't on the mark.  grokparsefailure will be something you see if the filter failed

Comment: Did this end up working ok?

Comment: This didn't end up working for me. I did however take from it and get a more robust config. I will see if I can post what I have.

Comment: Post it and I can test it with software that I work on that has a streamlined UI and has really good debugging and I could share that with you if you require.